# Connect to local SQL Server from .Net 4.8 Console Application Running in Docker Windows container

Tags: .net, sql-server, docker

I have a sample console application running on .NET 4.8 Framework. Application is able to connect local SQL Server. But when I run the application inside the docker container, I am not able to establish connection between the application and SQL Server.

Can anyone please help me with a solution?

This is my code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I am inside Docker!!!!");
        TestDBConnection();
        Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("End");
    }

    public static void TestDBConnection()
    {
        try
        {
            SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
            Console.WriteLine("I am inside Docker!!!");

            Console.WriteLine("Connecting to Local DB");
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Server=172.23.128.1\\LOCALHOST, 49172;Initial Catalog=config;User ID=sa;Password=Compusol@123;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;Connection Timeout=30;"))
            {
                connection.Open();
                Console.WriteLine("Connected to Local DD open");                    
            }
        }
        catch (SqlException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }

        Console.WriteLine("\nDone. Press enter.");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Docker Engine v20.10.14

Docker File

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/runtime:4.8 AS runtime
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
ENTRYPOINT ["DockerTestConnection.exe"]
```

I am publishing the application and running Docker inside the published folder. Publish folder will have all the application dependencies.

Comment: As an aside, `172.23.128.1\LOCALHOST, 49172` makes no sense as a connection string. The instance name will be ignored if you specify an explicit port number, because the only purpose of the instance name is to look up the port in the first place (through the SQL Server Browser service running on port 1434). So just `172.23.128.1,49172` would do (if that was reachable from the container, which apparently it isn't).

Answer (score 0):

When you are running your app inside a container, you will be better of using FQDNs instead of IP address to connect to your host Server instance. Depending on your particular setup, host OS and other factors, that name might vary. On Windows, it is {hostname}.mshome.net (or something like that). Then, your connection request will be routed to the host on a "Docker IP" address. You should consider reading up about the different networking and routing options available in a containerized world.

For example, your HOST might have the IP address 172.23.128.1. But it also will have additional IP on the vEthernet adapter, You should use that IP instead.

Answer (score 0):

firstly you need to check the network type i assume it is a "NAT network" because based on the type of the network the connection could  not be possible ,  then you need to verify the connection between your container and the sql server .
you run this command changing the IP adress and the port if you are not using 1433 port of sql server

```
Test-NetConnection -ComputerName xx.xxx.xx.xx -Port 1433 -InformationLevel "Detailed"
```

then if the test succeeded then problem is about the connection string
you can use this template it  works for mer :

```
"Server=xx.xxx.xx.xx\\MSSQLSERVER,1433;Initial Catalog=dbname;User Id=xxxx;Password=xxxxx;"
```

please verify the sqlserver instance you are using because i dont think that the instance name is localhost
by default it's `MSSQLSERVER`